# Webpack reference full URL for static assets

Tags: webpack

I compile email templates using webpack and in these I reference static assets that is available at my public path

I've set my public path as

```
webpackConfig.output = {
  filename: __DEV__ ? `[name].js` : `[name].[${config.compiler_hash_type}].js`,
  publicPath: "https://my_website.com"
}
```

With these loaders

```
webpackConfig.module.loaders.push(
  { test: /\.woff(\?.*)?$/,  loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=fonts/[name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
  { test: /\.woff2(\?.*)?$/, loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=fonts/[name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2' },
  { test: /\.otf(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'file?prefix=fonts/&name=fonts/[name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=font/opentype' },
  { test: /\.ttf(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=fonts/[name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
  { test: /\.eot(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'file?prefix=fonts/&name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
  { test: /\.svg(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=fonts/[name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
  { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,    loader: 'url?limit=8192' },
  { test: /\.(mp3|wav)$/,    loader: 'file?prefix=sounds/&name=sounds/[name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=audio/mpeg3' }
)
```

However, webpack compiles them to use relative paths, so in the email, they for example look like this

```
<img href="/public/images/abc.png"...
```

Which obviously won't work

How can I force it use the full, absolute URL?

Comment: I'm having the same question... there must be a way for Webpack to handle assets being served from a different server than the one hosting the current page...?